# How to catch UART Live data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, uart

I have built a mechanism for sending the letter 'O' every few seconds.
After that I catch the recieved Data with fgets in MATLAB.
fgets gives me a batch of lettters after some time which is not optimal because i want to see the arrival of each letter LIVE.
Is there a way to do it in matlab?
Thanks.

```
 while (1)
  {
      buffer[0] = 'O';
          Delay(1000);
          GPIO_PinOutSet(LED_PORT_E,15);
          Delay(1000);
                  USART_Tx(USART1,buffer[0]);
          GPIO_PinOutClear(LED_PORT_E,15);
      Delay(1000);
  }
```

Comment: try to explain better, please

Comment: Matlabs "gets" command is done manualy i gives me a result of what was send after sime time.
i need to see LIVE streaming in matlab

Comment: I did something similar, years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Drv08zKyRVU .
Below the video,  you can find a link with the code. I am sure it will solve your problems